# Почему Gulp watch постоянно обрабатывает файлы?

Tags: javascript, html, gulp, less

Добрый день всем! При запуске gulp watch начинает постоянно обновлять файлы? Он же ведь должен только при сохранении файла обновиться и замолчать?

gulpfile.js

```
var requireDir = require('require-dir');
// Require all tasks in gulp/tasks, including subfolders
requireDir('./gulp/tasks', { recurse: true });
```

из tasks watch.js:

```
var gulp   = require('gulp'),
watch  = require('gulp-watch')
config = require('../../config');

/*
* Смотрим за изменениями
*/

gulp.task('watch', function(){
watch([config.watch.html], function(event, cb) {
    gulp.start('html');
});
watch([config.watch.less], function(event, cb) {
    gulp.start('less');
});
watch(config.watch.jsInternal, function(event, cb) {
    gulp.start('js-internal');
});
watch([config.watch.jsExternal], function(event, cb) {
    gulp.start('js-external');
});
watch([config.watch.images], function(event, cb) {
    gulp.start('images');
});
watch([config.watch.sprites], function(event, cb) {
    gulp.start('sprites');
});
watch([config.watch.fonts], function(event, cb) {
    gulp.start('fonts');
});
});
```

Comment: Может быть вы складываете итоговые файлы в директорию, которую видит Gulp, следовательно он начинает их же заново обрабатывать?

Comment: В смысле предлагаете что бы сохранялись в другой папке? А можете пример накинуть?

Comment: @drtvader что еще за `gulp.start` ? впервый раз вижу.  И зачем еще подключать какой то `gulp-watch` ? в `gulp` `watch` из коробки есть.  Что то мудренно у вас сделано.